# How to use setevent to stop process handler

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to `createProcess` then inherit process handle to event handle

```
HANDLE app_event;

TCHAR* path = L"C:\\My.exe";
STARTUPINFO info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
info.cb = sizeof(info);
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);

ThreadId = processInfo.dwThreadId;


app_event = CreateEventW(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), processInfo.hProcess,
    GetCurrentProcess(),
    &app_event,
    0, FALSE,
    DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
```

and I'm creating thread for event

But when I call `setEvent` to stop process

The process don't stop and i got stuck at `WaitForSingleObject`

```
SetEvent(app_event);

WaitForSingleObject(app_thread, INFINITE);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Sorry I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DuplicateHandle` doesn't do what you think it does. It makes a new handle to an existing object. You seem to think it can be used to turn an object of one type into an object of another type. It cannot. A process handle cannot become an event handle.

This mis-understanding is compounded by your code's lack of error checking. The Win32 API won't raise exceptions. Errors are signaled by way of the API function return values. Which you ignore, unfortunately.

What you seem to be doing is trying to terminate a process in a co-operative manner. Signal an event to indicate termination is required. Then wait for the process to stop. That only works if the other process co-operates. There's no indication that is the case for you. You certainly cannot inject a termination event into the other process.

If the other process doesn't have a documented way to be signaled for termination then the best you can do is call `TerminateProcess`. If you are in control of the other process then you can agree on a co-operative procedure for termination. Use a named event that both process can gain access to.

I would like to repeat my main advice one more time. Always check for errors when calling Win32 functions. There's no one single way to do that, you must read the documentation carefully for each and every function that you call.